# Can't connect MySQL table to my PHP file

Tags: php

I've been trying to to connect a table I created in phpmyadmin to a php file,  but every time I try to access it I get this messsage:

> warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'jc'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/k1146376/www/lr/connect.php on line 2 Access denied for user 'jc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

This is the code I am using to call the table:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("connect.php");
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
$pages= array("products","cart");
if(in_array($_GET['page'],$pages)){
$page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
$page = "products";
}
} else {
$page = "products";
}
?>
```

this is my connect file:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','jc','password') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('products') or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: have you tried ' root ' for user ?

Comment: i have created a user on phpmyadmin, the name for the user is jc

Comment: this user has the right for read/write etc ?

Comment: yess ive granted all privileges

Comment: This old question has been abandoned without a resolution, so I am recommending it is put on hold.

Answer (score 3):

Some of your login credentials in `connect.php` is wrong. Put in the correct informations for your database and it'll work.

If you are on your own machine, you can go to `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin` and pick *Users* in the top navigation. Here you can add a new user or edit an existing one.

You are currently trying to login with the username `jc` and the password `password`.

Comment: ive chech them a million times and they are ok :(

Comment: yes jc is the username, localhost is the host, and password is password

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE USER 'jc'@%
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO jc
```

check that you're using the correct username/password.

stop using mysql_* (use mysqli_ , or better yet, PDO~)

check what mysql server version is running
check the relevant docs.
maybe its https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html  ?

Comment: ive check several times im about to kill myself